# Redirect of all the URLs that contain 1 word in specific, but that do not contain other words

Tags: nginx, regex, regular-expressions

I am migrating my website to another platform, but while I finish developing all the pages of the new website, I need my users to navigate between the 2 platforms.

So I need to make a 301 redirect of all the URLs that contain 1 word in specific, but that do not contain other words:

Example:

1. Old site: www2.misite.com
2. New site: www.misite.com

I need to redirect all URLs that contain the word "www2.misite.com/travel(.*)" but do not contain the words "reservation" and "hotel".

My server is Nginx, I do not know if this is done with a regular expression or with nginx statements.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Regular expressions and if, most likely. I've never heard of anyone taking this approach before, though I'm sure it's been done, I suggest you reconsider the entire approach.

Comment: I just want a way to do it, it does not have to be like I say it, but I do not know how.

Comment: I try location ~ /travel(.*)+/(.*)$ { if ($request_uri !~ "^/(reservation|hotel|faq)/\w+$"){ return 301 https://www.misite.com/$1; } } But not work for internal condition. :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem in the following way:

```
    location ~ /travel(.*)+/(.*)$ {
    if ($uri !~ "^(.*)/(reservation|hotel|faq)(.*)"){
        return 301 https://www.misite.com$request_uri;
    }
    autoindex on;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/sites/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try a regular expression with a negative look ahead for the two words you don't want forwarded.  You could do this in an if condition or in a rewrite rule.